# Is there a way to do 3D transforms with keypoints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-animation

I've created a 3D cube view transition that does the following:

- Creates a layer container.
- Adds the current view in 2D space.
- Adds the next view to the right and rotated 90 degrees (like in a cube)
- Performs an animation to rotate the cube.

Here's the code for that - its working fine. . . actual problem below:

```
- (CAAnimation*)makeRotationWithMetrics:(BBRotationMetrics*)metrics
{
    [CATransaction flush];
    CAAnimationGroup* group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.delegate = self;
    group.duration = metrics.duration;
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    group.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    CABasicAnimation* translationX = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.translation.x"];
    translationX.toValue = metrics.translationPointsX;
    CABasicAnimation* rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.rotation.y"];
    rotation.toValue = metrics.radians;

    CABasicAnimation* translationZ = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.translation.z"];
    translationZ.toValue = metrics.translationPointsZ;
    group.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rotation, translationX, translationZ, nil];

    return group;
}
```

At the end of the animation, I would like to perform a jiggle, as though the cube was mounted on a spring. I've tried playing a series of animations to rotate around the Y axis, gradually decaying.

I've set up a series of animations, but each ones starts from the origin, instead of the last point the layer got to. . . how can I fix that? One way would be to set the tranform on the layer first,

But is there a way to do 3D transforms with key-points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are looking for `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Instead of specifying a `toValue` you pass an array of `values` and optionally `keyTimes` including start and end values.

The starts from the origin problem comes from using `removedOnCompletion`. By doing so you are introducing a difference between the presentation (what is shown on screen) and the model (the property value of your layer). A cleaner approach is to explicitly set the end value and animate from the previous value to the end value. That will leave you in a clean state when the animation finishes.

Comment: Thanks David. . . CAKeyFrameAnimation can be used with 3D transforms? What do you specify as the values? . .  regarding starts from origin, you mean I should avoid setting that property? (I had it set to NO)

Comment: Ahh - I saw how to use key-frame animations with 3D transforms and rotations - trying now.

Comment: OK - I could still do it the way I was doing it if I saved the last toValue as fromValue. . . but key-frames will no-doubt be better.

Comment: @JasperBlues key frames is *the* solution when you want to animate the _same_ property through a series of values. Setting up a series of animations is sometimes necessary but mostly just messy.

Comment: @JasperBlues Avoiding the use of `removedOnCompletion` is just for cleanness. Animations in Core Animation doesn't modify the actual layer they are animating, they only change what is shown on screen. If you animate a property and check the value of the layer it is not going to change. That doesn't matter very much during the actual animation but if you don't remove the animation then you end up in a state where the value in the model and what is shown in screen differs. This can cause things like hit testing to be messed up. In short, it is bad to introduce unnecessary state difference.

Comment: @JasperBlues the last point applies to both CAKeyframeAnimation and CABasicAnimation